# Applying gravity to a player(image)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, gravity

I am making a car game and need my car to jump with gravity, though I have no idea of how to code it.

All the demo's i've found so far use balls and I'm struggling to understand which bits of the code I need to apply it to an image.

I want the car to jump when I click the mouse then obviously fall back down. Then to move the car left and right it's A and D.

Please can anyone help me? 
 My game URL is: http://users.aber.ac.uk/jae36/ftw/Crazy%20Road%20Trip%20Backup.html

And my current code for the whole game is as follows:

```
<script>

    var context = document.getElementById('canv').getContext("2d");
    var roadx = 0;
    var backgroundx = 0;
    var dx = 10;
    var combinex = 0;
    var W = canv.width;
    var H = canv.height;
    var carx = 180;
    var cary = 410;
    var score = 0;

    var canvback = new Image();
    canvback.src = "canvback.png";

    var canvroad = new Image();
    canvroad.src = "canvroad.png";

    var car = new Image();
    car.src = "car2.png";

    var rock = new Image();
    rock.src = "rock.png";

    var combine = new Image();
    combine.src = "combine.png";

    (function renderGame() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(renderGame);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

        context.drawImage(canvback, backgroundx, 0);
        context.drawImage(canvback, canvback.width-Math.abs(backgroundx), 0);
        context.drawImage(canvroad, roadx, 465);
        context.drawImage(canvroad, canvroad.width-Math.abs(roadx), 465);
        context.drawImage(combine, canv.width-Math.abs(combinex)+200, 420);

        if (Math.abs(backgroundx) > canvback.width) {
            backgroundx = 0;
        }

        backgroundx -= 0.5;

        if (Math.abs(roadx) > canvroad.width) {
            roadx = 0;
        }

        roadx -= 4;


        if (Math.abs(combinex) > context.canvas.width+600) {
            combinex = 0;
        }

        combinex -= 2;


        context.drawImage(car, carx, cary);

        scoring();
        context.font = "17px Times New Roman";
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillText("Score = " + score, 20, 30);
    }());

    function init() {
        canv = document.getElementById("canv");
        ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
        return setInterval(drawcar, 10);
    }

    function doKeyDown(evt){
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            if (carx - dx > 90) {
                carx -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 68:
            if (carx + dx < 800) {
                carx += dx;
            }
        }
    }


    function drawcar() {

        context.drawImage(car, carx, cary);
    }

    init();
    window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);

    function scoring() {
        setInterval(scores, 100);
    }

    function scores(){
        score += 0.001;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make events happen when input is received.

In `renderGame()`, you should have a function (called `update()` or `animate()` or something) that goes through all the conditions that could make your car animate. All of your input will then set variables that this update loop will use to perform the actual animation.

*Note: timestamp, and thus deltaTime, is in **milliseconds**. You probably want to convert this to seconds by dividing by 1000*

```
var game = game || {}; //Give yourself an object to store stuff in.

function doKeyDown(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 65:
        bIsMoveLeft = true;
        break;
    case 68:
        bIsMoveRight = true;
    }
}

function doKeyUp(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 65:
        bIsMoveLeft = false;
        break;
    case 68:
        bIsMoveRight = false;
    }
}

function doMouseDown(evt) {
  //bCanJump will allow you to prevent infinite-jumps. Logic is for you to find out.
  if (bCanJump) {
    car.verticalSpeed = 500;
  }
}

function doMouseUp(evt) {
  //Nothing needed when mouse is released.
}

function update(deltaTime) {
  if (bIsMoveLeft) {
    if (carx - (deltaTime * speed) > 90) {
            carx -= (deltaTime * speed);
    } else {
      carx = 90;
    }
  }

  if (bIsMoveRight) {
    if (carx + (deltaTime * speed) < 800) {
            carx += (deltaTime * speed);
    }
  }

  //The requested jump logic.
  cary += (deltaTime * car.verticalSpeed);
  car.verticalSpeed += gravity; //Assuming gravity is negative.

  if (cary < 410) {
    car.verticalSpeed = 0;
    cary = 410;

    //Maybe unlock a second jump. Maybe have a cooldown or something.
  }
}

//requestAnimationFrame provides a timestamp.
function renderGame(timestamp) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(renderGame);

  var deltaTime = timestamp - game.lastUpdate;
  game.lastUpdate = timestamp;

  update(deltaTime);

  //perform all of your necessary draws.
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(renderGame);
game.lastUpdate = window.performance.now();


window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
window.addEventListener('keyup', doKeyUp, true);
window.addEventListener('mousedown', doMouseDown, true);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', doMouseUp, true);
```

This is obviously incomplete... but it should tell you how to do the parts that are relevant to this question.

**Edit:**

Staying within what you have for your old example...

You will need an `doMouseDown()` function below `doKeyDown()`.

```
function doMouseDown(evt) {
  dy = 500; //Adjust this. Also, declare var dy = 0; at the top.
}
```

You'll then need `window.addEventListener('mousedown', doMouseDown, true);` below `window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);` to have that event fire each time the mouse button is pressed.

Then, in `renderGame()`, you will need to get how much time has gone by since the last `renderGame()` call. As it turns out, requestAnimationFrame gives you the current time in milliseconds to very high precision.

```
(function renderGame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(renderGame);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  ...
```

Turns into:

```
(function renderGame(time) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(renderGame);
  var deltaTime = time - window.lastTime;
  window.lastTime = time;

  context.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  ...
```

and later in `renderGame(time)` you will have.

```
...

cary += deltaTime * dy;
dy += -10; //Adjust this number in testing.

if (cary < 410) {
  dy = 0;
  cary = 410;
}

...
```

Comment: To more clearly illustrate: `car.verticalSpeed` is the value to determine how fast the car should move up. On the road, this will be 0. When the mouse button changes the vertical speed to be some value, let's say 500 for now, the car will begin to climb with each frame. At the same time, gravity (let's say -10 even though I didn't define it in the answer) will slow its climb, and eventually pull it back down. When it hits, `car.verticalSpeed` will be 0 again. Adjust the numbers as desired. Earth gravity is `-9.8 m/s^2` by the way.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't know what code to use.. This is an assignment and the deadline is in 11 hours..

Comment: Basically, you need a mousedown event to fire a function that sets a vertical speed to something that will move the car up (I called it car.verticalSpeed but `dy` fits your naming scheme better). You will then need to adjust `cary` by that vertical speed variable every time that `renderGame()` is called. Also, every time `renderGame()` is called, you will also need to reduce that vertical speed variable by some amount of gravity. This differs from the code in my answer, where I also fix moving back and forth.

Comment: Mousedown: Sets initial `dy`. `renderGame()` uses `dy` to adjust `cary` a tiny amount before using some `gravity`value to adjust `dy` until the car begins to fall and eventually lands.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to start this.. I would need to re-write my code.. And I just don't have the skill or the time.. Thank you for your trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I'm very new to javascript.. I still have to do collision detection... lord...

Comment: Okay edited. That's about all I can help with though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try my best and implement it. Thanks again.